# Spring AOP - Properly Configuring Retry Advice

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I am new to Spring AOP and have been experimenting a bit.

I am trying to setup Retry & Rate Limiter through Spring AOP for one of my project.
The use case is like this:-

1. Check if TPS is available. If not, throw `ThrottledException`
2. If a `ThrottledException` is thrown, `Retry`.

The issue I am running into is: This throttling & retry combo is running into an infinite loop (if TPS = 0). That is, retry is not stopping after 'x' attempts.

My Throttling Interceptor is (at a high level) like this:

```
@Before("<pointcut>")
public void invoke() throws ThrottlingException {
        if (throttler.isThrottled(throttleKey)) {
            throw new ThrottlingException("Call Throttled");
    }
}
```

My Retry Interceptor is like this:

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut="execution(* com.company.xyz.method())", throwing="exception")
public Object invoke(JoinPoint jp, ThrottlingException exception) throws Throwable {
    return RetryingCallable.newRetryingCallable(new Callable<Object>() {

        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {
                MethodSignature  signature = (MethodSignature) p.getSignature();
                Method method = signature.getMethod();
                return method.invoke(jp.getThis(), (Object[]) null);
        }

    }, retryPolicy).call();
}
```

Here `RetryingCallable` is a simple implementation (internal library written by someone in my company) that takes in a `RetryAdvice` and applies that.

My relevant spring-config is as follows:

```
<bean id="retryInterceptor" class="com.company.xyz.RetryInterceptor">
    <constructor-arg index="0"><ref bean="retryPolicy"/></constructor-arg> 
</bean>


<bean id="throttlingInterceptor" class="com.company.xyz.ThrottlingInterceptor">
    <constructor-arg><value>throttleKey</value></constructor-arg> 
</bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.xyz">
  <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect"/>
</context:component-scan>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

The issue here, as I see, is that on each `ThrottlingException` a new `Retry Advice` is being applied instead of the previous one being coming into affect.

Any inputs on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am *not* a Spring user, thus I am going to present a pure AspectJ solution here. It should work the same way in Spring AOP though. The only thing you need to change is switch from `@DeclarePresedence` to `@Order` for aspect precedence configuration as described in the [Spring AOP manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering).

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application().doSomething();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Doing something");
    }
}
```

**Throttling exception class:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class ThrottlingException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ThrottlingException(String arg0) {
        super(arg0);
    }
}
```

**Throttling interceptor:**

In order to emulate the throttling situation I created a helper method `isThrottled()` which returns `true` randomly in 2 out of 3 cases.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.util.Random;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

import de.scrum_master.app.ThrottlingException;

@Aspect
public class ThrottlingInterceptor {
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    @Before("execution(* doSomething())")
    public void invoke(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws ThrottlingException {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + " -> " + thisJoinPoint);
        if (isThrottled()) {
            throw new ThrottlingException("call throttled");
        }
    }

    private boolean isThrottled() {
        return RANDOM.nextInt(3) > 0;
    }
}
```

**Retry interceptor:**

Please note that the AspectJ annotation `@DeclarePrecedence("RetryInterceptor, *")` says that this interceptor is to be executed before any other ones. Please replace it with `@Order` annotations on both interceptor classes. Otherwise the `@Around` advice cannot catch exceptions thrown by the throttling interceptor.

Also worth mentioning is that this interceptor does not need any reflection in order to implement the retry logic, it directly uses the joinpoint within a retry loop in order to retry `thisJoinPoint.proceed()`. This can easily be factored out into a helper method or helper class implementing different kinds of retry behaviour. Just make sure to use the `ProceedingJoinPoint` as a parameter instead of a `Callable`.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.DeclarePrecedence;

import de.scrum_master.app.ThrottlingException;

@Aspect
@DeclarePrecedence("RetryInterceptor, *")
public class RetryInterceptor {
    private static int MAX_TRIES = 5;
    private static int WAIT_MILLIS_BETWEEN_TRIES = 1000;

    @Around("execution(* doSomething())")
    public Object invoke(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + " -> " + thisJoinPoint);
        ThrottlingException throttlingException = null;
        for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_TRIES; i++) {
            try {
                return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
            }
            catch (ThrottlingException e) {
                throttlingException = e;
                System.out.println("  Throttled during try #" + i);
                Thread.sleep(WAIT_MILLIS_BETWEEN_TRIES);
            }
        }
        throw throttlingException;
    }
}
```

**Console log for successful retry:**

```
RetryInterceptor -> execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething())
ThrottlingInterceptor -> execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething())
  Throttled during try #1
ThrottlingInterceptor -> execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething())
  Throttled during try #2
ThrottlingInterceptor -> execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething())
Doing something
```

**Console log for failed retry:**

```
RetryInterceptor -> execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething())
ThrottlingInterceptor -> execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething())
  Throttled during try #1
ThrottlingInterceptor -> execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething())
  Throttled during try #2
ThrottlingInterceptor -> execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething())
  Throttled during try #3
ThrottlingInterceptor -> execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething())
  Throttled during try #4
ThrottlingInterceptor -> execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething())
  Throttled during try #5
Exception in thread "main" de.scrum_master.app.ThrottlingException: call throttled
    at de.scrum_master.aspect.ThrottlingInterceptor.invoke(ThrottlingInterceptor.aj:19)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething_aroundBody0(Application.java:9)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething_aroundBody1$advice(Application.java:22)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething(Application.java:1)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:5)
```

Feel free to ask any follow-up questions related to my answer.

---

**Update:** I have no idea how your `RetryingCallable` and `RetryPolicy` classes/interfaces work, you did not tell me much about it. But I made up something and got it working like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public interface RetryPolicy<V> {
    V apply(Callable<V> callable) throws Exception;
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class DefaultRetryPolicy<V> implements RetryPolicy<V> {
    private static int MAX_TRIES = 5;
    private static int WAIT_MILLIS_BETWEEN_TRIES = 1000;

    @Override
    public V apply(Callable<V> callable) throws Exception {
        Exception throttlingException = null;
        for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_TRIES; i++) {
            try {
                return callable.call();
            }
            catch (ThrottlingException e) {
                throttlingException = e;
                System.out.println("  Throttled during try #" + i);
                Thread.sleep(WAIT_MILLIS_BETWEEN_TRIES);
            }
        }
        throw throttlingException;
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class RetryingCallable<V> {
    private RetryPolicy<V> retryPolicy;
    private Callable<V> callable;

    public RetryingCallable(Callable<V> callable, RetryPolicy<V> retryPolicy) {
        this.callable = callable;
        this.retryPolicy = retryPolicy;
    }

    public static <V> RetryingCallable<V> newRetryingCallable(Callable<V> callable, RetryPolicy<V> retryPolicy) {
        return new RetryingCallable<V>(callable, retryPolicy);
    }

    public V call() throws Exception {
        return retryPolicy.apply(callable);
    }
}
```

Now change the retry interceptor like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.DeclarePrecedence;

import de.scrum_master.app.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import de.scrum_master.app.RetryPolicy;
import de.scrum_master.app.RetryingCallable;

@Aspect
@DeclarePrecedence("RetryInterceptor, *")
public class RetryInterceptor {
    private RetryPolicy<Object> retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy<>();

    @Around("execution(* doSomething())")
    public Object invoke(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + " -> " + thisJoinPoint);
        return RetryingCallable.newRetryingCallable(
            new Callable<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object call() throws Exception {
                    return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
                }
            },
            retryPolicy
        ).call();
    }
}
```

The log output will be pretty much similar to what you saw before. For me this works nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am already using `@Ordered`. One question here, since I am using `@ThrowsException` advice I am kind of running into infinite loop. But your code seem to be working fine with `@Around`, what's the subtle difference that I am missing here?

Comment: Probably you mean `@AfterThrowing`. Well, that advice type, as the name implies, intercepts method executions _after_ they are already finished, `@Around` wraps itself _around_ method execution, i.e. can do something before and afterwards, catch and handle an exception, retry method execution etc. In `@AfterThrowing` is is already too late, the exception has been thrown and the method execution has finished. Furthermore, please check out the exception callstack in my log: The exception is thrown in `ThrottlingInterceptor.invoke`, so you might have had the wrong `@AfterThrowing ` pointcut.

Comment: Thanks,  I added a loop & retried it as you explained & this works, for now. One last thing though: in future I would like to use a generic Retry Policy (which provides good defaults like `3 retries`,  `bit for randomness` & `exponential backoff`) as I was using in my example above(`return RetryingCallable.newRetryingCallable(new Callable<Object>()`) any inputs on how I can add that in, instead of having a custom loop?

Comment: It depends on whether this retry stuff should happen synchronously or asynchronously. Where is this `RetryingCallable` from anyway? I found something in HBase client API, but no factory method there. Is it a home-brew thing? Before I suggest something based on your answer, one warning: If your callable method has a return value or a side effect the caller is relying on, you should not execute it asynchronously. Otherwise it is no problem with `void` return type and no expected synchronous side effects when the method is called.

Comment: Yeah, it an internal utility package used within my company. Basically it takes in a `RetryPolicy(which has decent defaults)` and then applies it the way we are doing in a loop. It takes in a `Callable` and just retries on the `call()` method. I tried wrapping the `joinpoint.proceed()` in its anonymous implementation & passing on to `RetryingCallable` to apply retries. I did it synchronously in the same thread. But somehow it did not work as expected. It just retried once. `Probably due to the @Around advice.`

Comment: I have just updated & extended my sample code in order to answer your additional question.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to work my solution accordingly. Hopefully it should work. I'll get back if I run into issues. Thanks for your time!