# Get method reference from JoinPoint

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I need to retry to execute the same method for a number of times inside Spring AOP @AfterThrowing. Is there any way that I can execute it using the JoinPoint reference? If not what is the best way. I need to know the answer without using spring-retry by annotating it in the target method.

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(DBRecoverable)")
public void repositoryClassMethods() {}

@AfterThrowing(value = "repositoryClassMethods()", throwing = "ex")
public void logExecutionTime(JoinPoint joinPoint, RuntimeException ex) throws Throwable {
    //Re-execute the method again
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, just wanted to pay your attention to spring retry library that might do what you want to achieve manually: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry

Comment: My requirement is to create an annotation where I can use it in my repository classes and handling @Recover in one single method instead of adding all the methods

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible using a `@AfterThrowing` pointcut, but you could use a `@Around` pointcut like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36823163/7952453).

Example:

```
@Around("repositoryClassMethods()")
public Object invoke(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    RuntimeException runtimeException = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TRIES; i++) {
        try {
            return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            runtimeException = e;
        }
    }
    throw runtimeException;
}
```

Comment: I want to amend because Gustavo said he was not sure: `@AfterThrowing` is definitely the wrong advice designator for it, only with `@Around` as presented here you can do it. In `@After` or `@AfterThrowing` you cannot change the control flow, only trigger additional actions **after** the method has already ended or thrown an exception. See also my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48787878/1082681), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56572489/1082681) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48237331/1082681). Reading the Spring AOP manual also helps.

Comment: The issue I'm having using "@Around" is, the actual exception will be thrown from "@Transactional" annotation in my case. Though if use "@Around" for the method that is annotated with "@Transactional" this method doesn't throw any exception related to transaction creation

Answer (score 0):

You might need get the target method by this:

```
public void filter(JoinPoint point) {
        Object[] args = point.getArgs();
        Class<?>[] argTypes = new Class[point.getArgs().length];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            argTypes[i] = args[i].getClass();
        }
        Method method;
            try {
                method = point.getTarget().getClass().getMethod(point.getSignature().getName(), argTypes);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
       if (method != null)
       // do with the method ref
}
```